# How can I redirect all traffic to a specific IP? (pseudo-proxy)

Tags: ssh, redirection

I have an SSH tunnel like this:

```
ssh -D 10.1.2.1:8080 -f -C -q -N name@ssh_server_ip
```

I have a computer on the local network (in fact VPN, but it's not important in this case) with an IP of 10.1.2.2.

I want to redirect all traffic from 10.1.2.2 (in fact from 10.1.2.2 - 10.1.2.80) to 10.1.2.1. I don't want to set a proxy in the web browser.

After all, 10.1.2.2 should connect via 10.1.2.1 to ssh_server_ip without any adjustment on 10.1.2.2.

This is necessary because some of the "computers" will be mobile devices and I can't force them to use a SOCKS5 pseudo-proxy.

I am using Debian.

Comment: Seriously? It can't so hard... I have tried this:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.1.2.1:8080
but it won't help

Answer (score 1):

You can use iptables and redsocks to redirect all your traffic to the socks5 proxy that you have already established.  It's nicely described on http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/.

This is how your `redsocks.conf` could look like if redsocks is running on your client (10.1.2.2):

```
redsocks {
    /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
     * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
     * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
     */
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 12345;

    // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
    ip = 10.1.2.1;
    port = 8080;

    // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
    type = socks5;

    // login = "foobar";
    // password = "baz";
}
```

In this case redsocks in running on port 12345 and you just have to tell iptables to redirect the tcp connections to redsocks:

```
# Create new chain
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS

# Ignore LANs and some other reserved addresses.
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to port 12345
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

# Any tcp connection made by `luser' should be redirected, put your username here.
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner luser -j REDSOCKS
```

For more information (e.g. on how to clean up iptables again) take a look at the redsocks website.